# Get first date of occurrence in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Take below data for example

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
     ('james','2019',0)
    ,('james','2020',1)
    ,('james','2021',1)
    ,('nik','2019',0)
    ,('nik','2020',1)

  ], ['name', 'year', 'flag'])
```

I want to add one more column "first_year_of_flag" which is the year when flag became 1 for the very first time, using pyspark.

so output should look like this -

| name | year | flag | first_year_of_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| james | 2019 | 0 | 2020 |
| james | 2020 | 1 | 2020 |
| james | 2021 | 1 | 2020 |
| nik | 2019 | 0 | 2020 |
| nik | 2020 | 1 | 2020 |

Answer (score 1):

I think `Window` + `join` is suitable for your case, you can first create a reference table:

```
# You can use group by -> first / min as well
ref_df = df\
    .filter(func.col('flag')==1)\
    .select(
        'name',
        func.first('year').over(Window.partitionBy('name').orderBy(func.asc('year'))).alias('first_year')
    ).distinct()

ref_df.show(10, False)
+-----+----------+
|name |first_year|
+-----+----------+
|james|2020      |
|nik  |2020      |
+-----+----------+
```

Then just do a left join with broadcasting:

```
df = df.join(func.broadcast(ref_df), on='name', how='left')
df.show(100, False)
+-----+----+----+----------+
|name |year|flag|first_year|
+-----+----+----+----------+
|james|2019|0   |2020      |
|james|2020|1   |2020      |
|james|2021|1   |2020      |
|nik  |2019|0   |2020      |
|nik  |2020|1   |2020      |
+-----+----+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **`window functions`** to get sum of flag value then determine when the flag value is `1` by `name` and ordering by `year`.

**Example:**

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
     ('james','2019',0)
    ,('james','2020',1)
    ,('james','2021',1)
    ,('nik','2019',0)
    ,('nik','2020',1)

  ], ['name', 'year', 'flag'])

aggregation_window = Window.partitionBy(col("name")).orderBy(col("year"))

aggregation_max = Window.partitionBy(col("name")).orderBy(col("year")).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

df=df.withColumn('aggregation_sum', sum('flag').over(aggregation_window)).\
withColumn("first_flag",when(col("aggregation_sum")=="1",lit(1))).\
withColumn("first_flag",expr("if(first_flag=1,year,0)")).\
withColumn("first_flag",max('first_flag').over(aggregation_max)).\
drop(*["aggregation_sum"])
df.show()

+-----+----+----+----------+
| name|year|flag|first_flag|
+-----+----+----+----------+
|james|2019|   0|      2020|
|james|2020|   1|      2020|
|james|2021|   1|      2020|
|  nik|2019|   0|      2020|
|  nik|2020|   1|      2020|
+-----+----+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

A `when().otherwise()` within a `min` window would work.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('first_year_of_flag',
               func.min(func.when(func.col('flag') == 1, func.col('year'))).
               over(wd.partitionBy('name'))
               ). \
    show()

# +-----+----+----+------------------+
# | name|year|flag|first_year_of_flag|
# +-----+----+----+------------------+
# |  nik|2019|   0|              2020|
# |  nik|2020|   1|              2020|
# |james|2019|   0|              2020|
# |james|2020|   1|              2020|
# |james|2021|   1|              2020|
# +-----+----+----+------------------+
```

Essentially, only find min of years for which the flag is equal to 1 in the partition.